# How do I set consumer priority in celery - rabbitmq set up?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

To implement data locality, I need consumer priorities in my celery - rabbitmq set up, i.e, consumer picking up tasks from certain queue with a preference.

I found that Rabbitmq supports consumer priority:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html

How can I use this feature?

In case it is not already implement how can I implement it?

In the rabbitmq example code (provided in the link), `x-priority` argument has been and provided to basicConsume. How can I implement this in celery code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had posted this question in celery issues page too. This feature has been incorporated in developmental version:

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3098

At consumer end, you can define `x-priority` argument in queues to consume from.
In the below example, consumer picks up tasks from celery queue with priority 0 and from hipri with priority 10.

Example:

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('celery', Exchange('celery', type='direct'), routing_key='celery',
          consumer_arguments={'x-priority': 0}),
    Queue('hipri', Exchange('hipri', type='direct'), routing_key='hipri',
          consumer_arguments={'x-priority': 10}),
)
```

Comment: I am not much familiar with Celery. Can you give a more complete example of the above? Where exactly I shall add this code? Currently I am accessing our RMQ queues as e.g. `task_run_grouping = app.signature('test.run_realtime_grouping', (context,)).set(queue='my_rabbitmq_queue')`